# Creating GUI for DVD

Tags: user-interface, dvd

Is it possible to create some GUI to operate files on a DVD disk when it's inside a hardware DVD player?

Yes, I know I can convert my avi files into DVD format and attach some menu to them (there is a lot of software for doing this), but what if I don't want my avi's to be converted? Is there a way to keep them the way they are and run them through some own written graphical shell?

Answer (score 1):

that would depend on the hardware and software incorporated into the DVD player you are using but generally for an of the shelf DVD player i would say no it is not posible

Comment: Thank you. It's sad to realize that we still have to deal with terrible firmware that limits our possibilities. For example, my Supra player sorts files as it wants to and shows only few first characters of a filename. I only look for a way to make my shelf player more usable and friendly.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends upon your DVD player firmware. Generally this is not allowed.